# Hide go to top button when page is fully scrolled to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have a button on my wordpress theme homepage that is used for going to the top of the page. I want to hide it when page is fully scrolled to the top. Here is my code:

```
(function($) {



var version = '@VERSION',

    defaults = {

      exclude: [],

      excludeWithin:[],

      offset: 0,

      direction: 'top', // one of 'top' or 'left'

      scrollElement: null, // jQuery set of elements you wish to scroll (for $.smoothScroll).

                          //  if null (default), $('html, body').firstScrollable() is used.

      scrollTarget: null, // only use if you want to override default behavior

      beforeScroll: function() {},  // fn(opts) function to be called before scrolling occurs. "this" is the element(s) being scrolled

      afterScroll: function() {},   // fn(opts) function to be called after scrolling occurs. "this" is the triggering element

      easing: 'swing',

      speed: 600,

      autoCoefficent: 2 // coefficient for "auto" speed

    },



    getScrollable = function(opts) {

      var scrollable = [],

          scrolled = false,

          dir = opts.dir && opts.dir == 'left' ? 'scrollLeft' : 'scrollTop';



      this.each(function() {



        if (this == document || this == window) { return; }

        var el = $(this);

        if ( el[dir]() > 0 ) {

          scrollable.push(this);

        } else {

          // if scroll(Top|Left) === 0, nudge the element 1px and see if it moves

          el[dir](1);

          scrolled = el[dir]() > 0;

          if ( scrolled ) {

            scrollable.push(this);

          }

          // then put it back, of course

          el[dir](0);

        }

      });



      // If no scrollable elements, fall back to <body>,

      // if it's in the jQuery collection

      // (doing this because Safari sets scrollTop async,

      // so can't set it to 1 and immediately get the value.)

      if (!scrollable.length) {

        this.each(function(index) {

          if (this.nodeName === 'BODY') {

            scrollable = [this];

          }

        });

      }



      // Use the first scrollable element if we're calling firstScrollable()

      if ( opts.el === 'first' && scrollable.length > 1 ) {

        scrollable = [ scrollable[0] ];

      }



      return scrollable;

    },

    isTouch = 'ontouchend' in document;



$.fn.extend({

  scrollable: function(dir) {

    var scrl = getScrollable.call(this, {dir: dir});

    return this.pushStack(scrl);

  },

  firstScrollable: function(dir) {

    var scrl = getScrollable.call(this, {el: 'first', dir: dir});

    return this.pushStack(scrl);

  },



  smoothScroll: function(options) {

    options = options || {};

    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.smoothScroll.defaults, options),

        locationPath = $.smoothScroll.filterPath(location.pathname);



    this

    .unbind('click.smoothscroll')

    .bind('click.smoothscroll', function(event) {

      var link = this,

          $link = $(this),

          exclude = opts.exclude,

          excludeWithin = opts.excludeWithin,

          elCounter = 0, ewlCounter = 0,

          include = true,

          clickOpts = {},

          hostMatch = ((location.hostname === link.hostname) || !link.hostname),

          pathMatch = opts.scrollTarget || ( $.smoothScroll.filterPath(link.pathname) || locationPath ) === locationPath,

          thisHash = escapeSelector(link.hash);



      if ( !opts.scrollTarget && (!hostMatch || !pathMatch || !thisHash) ) {

        include = false;

      } else {

        while (include && elCounter < exclude.length) {

          if ($link.is(escapeSelector(exclude[elCounter++]))) {

            include = false;

          }

        }

        while ( include && ewlCounter < excludeWithin.length ) {

          if ($link.closest(excludeWithin[ewlCounter++]).length) {

            include = false;

          }

        }

      }



      if ( include ) {

        event.preventDefault();



        $.extend( clickOpts, opts, {

          scrollTarget: opts.scrollTarget || thisHash,

          link: link

        });



        $.smoothScroll( clickOpts );

      }

    });



    return this;

  }

});



$.smoothScroll = function(options, px) {

  var opts, $scroller, scrollTargetOffset, speed,

      scrollerOffset = 0,

      offPos = 'offset',

      scrollDir = 'scrollTop',

      aniProps = {},

      aniOpts = {},

      scrollprops = [];



  if ( typeof options === 'number') {

    opts = $.fn.smoothScroll.defaults;

    scrollTargetOffset = options;

  } else {

    opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.smoothScroll.defaults, options || {});

    if (opts.scrollElement) {

      offPos = 'position';

      if (opts.scrollElement.css('position') == 'static') {

        opts.scrollElement.css('position', 'relative');

      }

    }



    scrollTargetOffset = px ||

                        ( $(opts.scrollTarget)[offPos]() &&

                        $(opts.scrollTarget)[offPos]()[opts.direction] ) ||

                        0;

  }



  opts = $.extend({link: null}, opts);

  scrollDir = opts.direction == 'left' ? 'scrollLeft' : scrollDir;



  if ( opts.scrollElement ) {

    $scroller = opts.scrollElement;

    scrollerOffset = $scroller[scrollDir]();

  } else {

    $scroller = $('html, body').firstScrollable();

  }



  aniProps[scrollDir] = scrollTargetOffset + scrollerOffset + opts.offset;



  opts.beforeScroll.call($scroller, opts);



  speed = opts.speed;



  // automatically calculate the speed of the scroll based on distance / coefficient

  if (speed === 'auto') {



    // if aniProps[scrollDir] == 0 then we'll use scrollTop() value instead

    speed = aniProps[scrollDir] || $scroller.scrollTop();



    // divide the speed by the coefficient

    speed = speed / opts.autoCoefficent;

  }



  aniOpts = {

    duration: speed,

    easing: opts.easing,

    complete: function() {

      opts.afterScroll.call(opts.link, opts);

    }

  };



  if (opts.step) {

    aniOpts.step = opts.step;

  }



  if ($scroller.length) {

    $scroller.stop().animate(aniProps, aniOpts);

  } else {

    opts.afterScroll.call(opts.link, opts);

  }

};



$.smoothScroll.version = version;

$.smoothScroll.filterPath = function(string) {

  return string

    .replace(/^\//,'')

    .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')

    .replace(/\/$/,'');

};



// default options

$.fn.smoothScroll.defaults = defaults;



function escapeSelector (str) {

  return str.replace(/(:|\.)/g,'\\$1');

}



})(jQuery);
```

your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is based on user events so something like this to cover mousescroll and scroll

```
 $(window).bind( "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll scroll", function(e){
 if (document.body.scrollTop == 0) {
    // do this
 }

 })
```